# How to use AWS Cognito as a unified SSO?

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, amazon-cognito

I would like to have only one login screen, registration, profile and password recovery for all projects in my company. Basically a unified login or SSO.

So I made these screens using AWS Cognito and hosted them on the **sso.mycompany.com** domain and it's working fine.

But now I need to implement these screens in my other projects. How can I do this? I can't just copy the files, as this was done in Vue.js, and I would like to put these screens in projects done in Laravel, Wordpress, React, etc;

I thought of using an iframe loading sso.mycompany.com, but how do I return user data after login to the app that opened the iframe?

Basically that's it, I have authentication screens hosted on the **sso.mycompany.com** domain and I would like to use them on **projectx.com**, **projecty.com**, **mycompany.com**, etc.

Comment: Could you just check for the presence of an auth token and if it doesn't exist, redirect the users to sso.mycompany.com to authenticate.

Comment: The cognito only recognizes authenticated users in the same domain. If I sign in in sso.mycompany.com and go to abc.com and requests Amplify.Auth.getCurrentAuthenticatedUser it will return null, because the domains are different.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution that might work for you and might give you some ideas on how you could put together a solution.  Unfortunately, Cognito out of the box doesn't come with a unified/universal login experience that you require.  It also doesn't come with a lot of other features you might see from the big IdP platforms, but that is another discussion for another time :) The whole foundation of this solution is based off of a single domain, cookies and JWTs(access token, id token and a refresh token). It will still work for your apps on other domains, but the experience for your end users will be a bit sub optimal compared to if all your apps were on the same domain.

Because an app like projectx.com sits on a different domain then sso.mycompany.com, you have to somehow get a access token over to projectx.com after the user logs in through mycompany.com.  You can simply just pass the access token through as a query param when you redirect the user back to projectx.com after a successful login on sso.mycompany.com.

I had a much longer answer with details, but stackoverflow won't let me post because it thinks my answer is spam??? Check my profile on how to contact me if you want the longer version with details.